# Sinatra pass anonymous block

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to Sinatra and am trying to implement the following:

REST service with get method whose action block can be provided. Something like:

```
class C1
  get '/something' do
     <some action to be provided later>
  end

  post '/something' do
     <some action to be provided later>
  end
end

C1.new
C1.get_block = { "Hello from get" }
C1.post_block = { "Hello from post" }
```

Is it possible to do something like above? I am designing an intercepting service which can be used to perform different actions depending on conditions

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick. I've added arrays so you can register multiple blocks that should be executed upon a GET/POST requests.

```
class C1
  @@get_blocks = []
  @@post_blocks = []

  def register_get(block)
    @@get_blocks << block
  end

  def register_post(block)
    @@post_blocks << block
  end

  get '/something' do
     @@get_blocks.each do |block|
       block.call(params)
     end
  end

  post '/something' do
     @@post_blocks.each do |block|
       block.call(params)
     end
  end
end

C1.new
C1.register_get { |params| "Hello from get" }
C1.register_post { |params| "Hello from post" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @MartinKonecny answered the question using a very nice dynamic and effective approach...

...But please allow me to suggest a different approach, assuming that the code itself is static and that it is activated according to a set of conditions.

I know that using [the Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) you could alternate controllers for the same route, so that if one controller doesn't answer the request, the next one is tested.

I believe that [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) could be used in the same way, so that when the first route fails, the second route is attempted.

A short demonstration of the concept (not an actual app code), using [the Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) would look something like this:

```
require 'plezi'

listen

class C1
  def index
     "Controller 1 answers"
  end
  def hello
     false
  end
end

class C2
  def show
     "Controller 2 shows your request for: #{params[:id]}"
  end
  def hello
     'Hello World!'
  end
end

route '/(:id)', C1
route '/(:id)', C2 

exit # exit the terminal to test this code.
```

This way, for the path [localhost:3000/](http://localhost:3000/), the `C1` class answers. But, the route for `C1` fails the restful request for the path [localhost:3000/1](http://localhost:3000/1), so the route for `C2` answers that request, attempting to show object with `id==1`.

This is easy to see when accessing the [localhost:3000/hello](http://localhost:3000/hello) route - the first route fails, and the second one is then attempted.

If you don't need to define the blocks dynamically, perhaps this approach - which I assume to be available also in [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) - will be more easy to code and maintain.

If this isn't available using Sinatra, you could probably imitate this approach using a "routing" class as a controller on your Sinatra app.

Another approach would be to specify the conditions in a `case` statement, calling different methods according to each situation.

```
class C1
  get '/something' do
     case 
     when true # condition
        # do something
     when true # condition
        # do something
     when true # condition
        # do something
     when true # condition
        # do something
     else
       # do something
     end
  end
end
```